# Vim makeprg with multiple commands (cd + make)

Tags: vim

I want vim to run `makeprg` with two commands, namely: `cd\ cmt;make;`
but when I do so, it get stuck on the make command.

To clarify, when I mean get stuck, I mean that it ends compilation but it doesn't return to `vim`, I need to strike C-c to cancel compilation, but it also breaks the compilation log interpretation from the compiler, and I can't get the `cwin` with the compilation errors interpreted.

Any ideas?

Comment: What about `cd\ cmt\ &&\ make`?

Comment: @romainl yes, thanks! You can post it as an answer. The solution is to use `&&` instead.

Comment: Just in case if this is an instance of the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). It is possible to run `make` in an arbitrary directory using `-C` option. In your case this would be: `make -Ccmt`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use this form:

```
set makeprg=cd\ cmt\ &&\ make
```

If you don't want to escape spaces:

```
let &makeprg = "cd cmt && make"
```

--- edit ---

The problem with your initial attempt is that the shell in which `makeprg` is executed is non-interactive and thus supposed to exit after the execution of a command. Sending it two commands in a row doesn't seem like a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
set makeprg=javac\ %\ \&\ \java\ %<
```

`javac\ %` will compile your code and  `java\ %<` will execute it.